# Does Python's standard library have a data structure that's a list that only allows unique items and allows unhashable items?

Tags: python

For convenience, I want a list that only allows unique items to be added.

```py
class UniqueList(list):
    def append(self, new_item):
        for existing_item in self:
            if new_item is existing_item:
                return
        super().append(new_item)
```

This code seems to work perfectly, despite being somewhat inefficient - each time you add an item, it needs to do a search through all of its items to see if it's already in there. It's more efficient, but less convenient, to just filter out duplicates once, at the end, when you're doing adding all your items, but in this case, I prefer convenience over efficiency (or I wouldn't be using Python).

Does this already exist in the standard library somewhere?

A `set` doesn't allow values that can't be hashed, which I frequently deal with, or I'd use a `set`.

It's also possible, but not always convenient, to remove duplicates after adding all your items to the list (for example with list comprehension). I find the above code to be more convenient, and safe, than remembering to remove duplicate items at the end.

To be clear, all I want to know is if I should keep writing the code above in my projects when I need it, or if this already exists in the standard library, and I just need to import it.

My code doesn't take into consideration things like modifying one element to be equal to another without using the `append` method, which can result in duplicates in the `UniqueList` instance, which I'm hoping the Python standard library's version of my `UniqueList` would prevent (if there is one).

Comment: How would the data structure you are asking for work if you add two lists, `[1, 2, 3]` and `[2, 3]`, and then later you remove `1` from the first list?

Comment: To literally answer your question: no.

Comment: So the devil-in-the-details is the `in` operation. For a `list` that will be `O(N)` for a `set` that would be `O(1)` though as you noted requires the elements to be hashable. The compromise in the middle would be a sorted container that will at least get you `O(logN)` lookups using a binary search.

Comment: @mkrieger1 if I understand your question correctly, the 2 lists are 2 distinct objects, so if they are both contained in a `UniqueList` instance, which is mutable, there's no issues. You'll have a `UniqueList` instance with 2 distinct lists that just happen to have the same items

Comment: @CoryKramer so in english, what you're saying is that my code is inefficient, because every time you add an item, it needs to do a lookup to compare it against every other item? I'm not concerned with sub-millisecond speeds for my use cases, but that's good to keep in mind

Comment: I think @mkrieger1 meant if you have a `UniqueList([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3]])` and now you mutate the first element i.e. `UniqueList[0].pop(0)` maybe? Now, your unique list would have duplicates -> `UniqueList([[2, 3], [2, 3]])`. I mean that's the point of not allowing non-hashable type in sets.

Comment: @Ch3steR for some use cases, that might matter. It won't crash, because the 2 lists are distinct objects, and for my use case, that's not a problem

Comment: @John `UniqueList([[2, 3], [2, 3]])` does have two distinct list objects doesn't it?

Comment: @Ch3steR in memory, they are 2 separate objects, which is the only thing I care about, and the only thing my overridden `append` method's if-statement cares about

Comment: Your data structur won't append duplicate elements, but allow to set to duplicate elements? I don't know any data structure that is defined this way.

Comment: So if you called your overridden `append` method twice with a list literal `[2, 3]` as argument, would you expect one or two lists to be added?

Comment: Is that you only want to add only distinct objects as in each object has a different `id`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 `[2,3] is [2,3]` is `False`, so yes, that's 2 distinct objects.

Comment: @Ch3steR yes. Only objects with different IDs

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny hu. Turns out you're right - `in` doesn't check for strict equality like I thought.

Comment: @John *My code doesn't take into consideration things like modifying one element to be equal to another without using the append method, which can result in duplicates in the UniqueList instance, which I'm hoping the Python standard library's version of my UniqueList would prevent* - so you mean you want to have immutable objects inside the `UniqueList`. Immutable objects are hashable, mutable objects cannot be hashed. `list` is mutable hence not hashable. What you want is impossible as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of anything in the standard python library or any other python libraries that do this.

As pointed out from some comments you can run into some problems if you accidentally mix a list and a UniqueList.

Probably the best/most efficient solution for this use case is to write your own class that consists of a set (for hashable items) and a list (for unhashable items). This could be a hassle as you would need to implement loads of methods such as `__iter__`, `append` (or `add`) and so on.

If that seems to much work, just use your UniqueList and be careful when using it.

Also, both of the solutions I mentioned still have a problem. Imagine that your data type has two lists inside: `[2]` and `[2, 3]`. If you access the first list and append a 3 to it you would end up with `[2, 3]` and `[2, 3]`. I *think* this could be mitigated if you implement your own class by overriding `__setattr__`, but I don't think it is that trivial to do so.

Comment: On further thought it is very difficult to prevent the last problem i mentioned. If a list is inserted you could probably prevent it being modified from the class, but if someone has a reference to that variable, it could be modified from outside the class (since the reference is the same both places would be modified). This probably could be mitigated by copying the value on insertion, but that means a lot of overhead

Comment: That's the point of having immutable objects. If OP doesn't want to change the state of objects after adding into UniqueList they want an immutable object. You can use `tuple` for `list`, `frozenset` for `set`, tuple of tuples for dict maybe? then use a simple set to store them.